# MySQL Add foreign key to existing table PHP

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a built database with all tables set using **INNODB** and **Foreign Keys**. Now I need to modify a single table and add a new column which references another table. My query is:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD newcol INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test
FOREIGN KEY (newcol) 
REFERENCES othertable(id);
```

I get the following error:

```
"#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails."
```

All the other tables contain data, but I know that if I drop the `test` table and create it with foreign key it will work. If I drop test table it will delete a lot of records and I want to avoid copying data and re-inserting it.

Can anyone show me how to add a new column via a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means you have values in `newcol` that do not exist in `othertable id` column. By adding a column of `INT NOT NULL`, you set all the initial values for that column to `0`. If you do not have an id of `0` in `othertable`, you have a key mismatch

Try this query:

```
SELECT  newcol 
FROM    test
WHERE   newcol NOT IN (
    SELECT  id
    FROM    othertable
)
```

if you get any results returned, then you have key values in `newcol` that violate the FK restraints

Comment: what should i do to fix it so that i add foreign key

Comment: you need to update the test newcol values so that they correspond to the values within othertable id column.